# How can I find the selected tab in tab bar scheme from the child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I use a tab bar to display three filtered views of the same data using a single table view controller. To determine the appropriate filter I need to find out which tab was selected from the child view controller. I used storyboard to create this structure so I don't have a tab bar view controller.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of IB hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible ways:

1. in your child view controller

   UITabBarController *tvc = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;

   NSInteger index = tvc.selectedIndex;
2. use a singleton to hold the selectedIndex

Comment: Thank You. I was able to use 'mode = (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! as Int' also. But your suggestion #1 is clearly the right way.